# Unwind withDefault()

Tags: collections, groovy

Having the code:

```
def res = [:].withDefault{ 0 }
someList.each{ res[ it ] += getFreq( it ) }
```

I want to remove the defaulting of the values, so that the call `res[ 33 ]` doesn't insert the new pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as easy as assign the donor to another var:

```
def original = [:]
def res = original.withDefault{ 0 }
someList.each{ res[ it ] += getFreq( it ) }
assert null == orininal[ 333 ]
assert 0 == res[ 333 ]
assert 0 == orininal[ 333 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `MapWithDefault` does not seem to have an accessor to the delegate.  Sledgehammer: `res.@delegate`

Comment: `res` is a `Map`.  Why is it that you want to refer to `res.@delegate`?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown `res` is a `MapWithDefault` there and because `MapWithDefault` has no accessor (unlike `ListWithDefault`) and this is the only way i was able to get the original back. As i stated: sledgehammer.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you are using `withDefault()` to make your `+=` expression self-initializing. However, in such cases I generally prefer to do that initialization on the fly using the elvis `?:` operator:

```
def res = [:]
res.getMetaClass().putMoreFreq = { res[ it ] = (res[ it ] ?: 0) + getFreq( it ) }
someList.each{ res.putMoreFreq(it) }
assert null == res[ 333 ]
```

If you find this answer to be non-responsive, I'll be happy to take it down.

**EDIT**: with code changes as suggested in comments.

Comment: My point, @injecteer , is that `withDefault()` seems like a rather broad brush with which to attempt to paint a tiny corner of the map semantics, whereas the null-replacement afforded by using elvis `?:` addresses only the desired behavior. Of course you can still apply the accumulation behavior to the map as a whole just by defining a new method on the map, something like:

`res.getMetaClass().putMoreFreq = { res[ it ] = (res[ it ] ?: 0) + getFreq( it ) }`